# Can a VSCode snippet make three substitutions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I have written a VSCode snippet that makes two substitutions to the clipboard content.
For instance, this snippet changes "a" characters into "x" and "e" characters into "y"

```
    "t2": {
        "prefix": "t2",
        "body": [
            "${CLIPBOARD/(a)|(e)/${1:?x:y}/g}"
        ],
        "description": "Makes two substitutions to the clipboard"
    },
```

Using this snippet, if I cut the text "This snippet changes the clipboard" and I execute the snippet, the pasted text is "This snippyt chxngys thy clipboxrd".
My question is: Is it possible to create a snippet that applies three substitutions? For instance, "a" into "x", "e" into "y" and "i" into "z", obtaining "Thzs snzppyt chxngys thy clzpboxrd" in the example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can change as many as you want.  I made this snippet for another answer:

```
"color conditional": {
    "prefix": "_hex",
    "body": [

      "let color = '${1};",      
      "let hex = '${1/(white)|(black)|(red)/${1:+#fff}${2:+#000}${3:+#f00}/}';" //works      
    ],
    "description": "conditional color"
  },
```

[image: color conditional snippet demo]

See [vscode if/else conditions in user defined snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381007/vscode-if-else-conditions-in-user-defined-snippet/57383247#57383247).

for one example but in your case try:

`"${CLIPBOARD/(a)|(e)|(i)/${1:+x}${2:+y}${3:+z}/g}"`

instead of using the if/else conditional, you can use any number of `if`'s.

[image: snippet multiple replacement]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried to use succesive ifs, but I did not succeded. With your example, now I understand it.