# VS Code snippets: workaround for applying transforms to choices?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

VS Code snippets have the ability to apply transforms to the inputs of a tabstop.

However, if the tabstop lists various choices for the user to pick from, as defined here, in the [format described here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_choice), then one cannot apply transforms to those choices, because transforms only work for terms that look like `transform` (i.e. are regex based) ([see the EBNF definition here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_choice)).

Are there any workarounds that would allow us to still have some semblance of choice, along with a transform?

Comment: You still cannot do transforms on choice results.  Can you give a concrete example of what you are trying to do:  what the choices look like and how you want to transform them.

Comment: @Mark I am mostly trying to distill your answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57383247/3486684. I cannot change the title of that question without violating the intent of the original question's body, but to me the most significant part of your answer there was the fact that one can very roughly simulate choice using regex `|` operators and VS Code snippets' `if`/`else` operators.